# Trouble assigning generic type T to type T

Tags: java, generics, stack, queue

I just recently started using java after about a year of using c++. In c++ I could easily assign generic type T to another generic type T. The issue here is that in java type T cannot be a primitive and will always be an object. So java says I can't assign an object to T (a generic-type-variable). Is there a way that I can convert T back into a primitive and not an object so that I can assign T to T?

Context if anyone needs it: I'm coding a stack using a queue as a private member for a project (at university) so for the top() function of the Stack class the only way I can get the top I have to dequeue the queue (the private member). But as always with top you can't actually delete the top you just read whats there, so I copy the queue and then dequeue the copied queue. The issue is that although dequeue returns generic type T java sees it as an object and not a generic type.

Here is the dequeue() function of the Queue class:

```
public T dequeue(){
    return dataStructure.remove(0);
}
```

(where dataStructure holds generic type T's) 
and here is my top() function for the stack class:

```
public T top(){
    Queue temp = new Queue<T>(elements);
    T element = temp.dequeue();
    return element;
}
```

elements is the private Queue member

Comment: Yes all the classes are defined with generic types

Comment: `Queue temp = new Queue<T>(elements);` ===> `Queue<T> temp = new Queue<T>(elements);`

Comment: Wow can't believe I didn't see that. Embarrassing.  Thanks so much for the help though!